# Java code for aggregation command of MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to read the document of nested list of another list of a document using mongoTemplate of Java code, I have tried from almost a day for the same but facing difficulty in doing that, kindly help me to sort it out.

Document in my database is:

```
{ 
"_id" : "DEPT5",  
"subDepartmentList" : [
    {
        "subDepartmentId" : "SUBDEPT19", 
        "subDepartmentName" : "ABCD",  
        "labServiceList" : [
            {
                "_id" : "123abc", 
                "departmentId" : "DEPT5", 
                "subDepartmentId" : "SUBDEPT19", 
                "labServiceName" : "serviceOne" 
            }, 
            { 
                "_id" : "123def", 
                "departmentId" : "DEPT5", 
                "subDepartmentId" : "SUBDEPT19",  
                "labServiceName" : "hello"
             }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "subDepartmentId" : "SUBDEPT21", 
        "subDepartmentName" : "IJKL", 
        "labServiceList" : [
            {
                "_id" : "456abc", 
                "departmentId" : "DEPT5", 
                "subDepartmentId" : "SUBDEPT21" 
                "labServiceName" : "hello"                
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Query in my shell window is as follows:

```
db.labServiceMasters.aggregate([{$unwind: '$subDepartmentList'},
  {$unwind: '$subDepartmentList.labServiceList'},
  {$match: {'subDepartmentList.labServiceList._id': '123def'}},
  {$project: {_id: 0, labService: '$subDepartmentList.labServiceList'}}
])
```

The above query works fine in my shell window. I tried to implement the same query using Java code below, but it did not work.

```
DBObject unwind1 = new BasicDBObject("$unwind" , "$subDepartmentList");
unwind1 = new BasicDBObject("$unwind" , "$subDepartmentList.labServiceList");


DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("_id", "123def")); 

DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("_id", 0)
 .append("subDepartmentList.labServiceList", 1));

AggregationOutput output=mongoTemplate.getCollection(MasterCollection).aggregate(unwind1, match, project);
System.out.println("OUTPUT: "+output);
for(DBObject result: output.results()){
    System.out.println("INside for each loop of Results.");
    System.out.println(result);
 }
```

Please help me to solve the above query. Any suggestions would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not the same. You wrote the `$match` differently. You also have "two" `$unwind` operations but your java code only defines **one**, and you overwrite the variable definition with what looks like the second `$unwind`. So have I asked you before something along the lines of *"What have you tried?"*. Because this is still not a code writing service. So "tried" does mean to make a "reasonable effort". And all the code problems here are really easily solved by simply paying attention to detail.

Comment: @NeilLunn: I have tried the same before also, but it did not work. Following is the other lines which I wrote before I post this question.  
   DBObject unwind1 = new BasicDBObject("$unwind" , "$subDepartmentList");
   DBObject unwind2 = new BasicDBObject("$unwind" , "$subDepartmentList.labServiceList");  and finally I passed these two to the  aggregate funcion.

Comment: What I just told you is you actually have not "tried" hard enough. These are not problems. They are basic errors and very basic errors.  At a quick glance I spotted all of them. Please try and do the same.

Comment: Ok fine, thanks for your suggestion, I will try to sort it out and will get back here.

Comment: OMG :-) :-) Thanks a lot Neil for making me to work it on my own :-) Its working now, and I am happy for your suggestion :-) :-)